# Ajax request to PHP save method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Im sending an array of values using **AJAX** and my frameword it's **CODEIGNITER 3**

This is the method

```
$.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "<?php echo base_url()?>empleadoController/save_empleado",
          type:"POST",
          data: {
            "fecha_ingreso": fecha_ingreso,
            "direccion": direccion ,
            "nombrecompleto": nombrecompleto,
            "cedula": cedula ,
            "carnet":carnet ,
            "telefono": telefono ,
            "observaciones": observaciones ,
            "email": email,
            "dominioempleado": dominioempleado ,
            "usr_open": usr_open ,
            "usr_oda": usr_oda ,
            "usr_qflow": usr_qflow ,
            "usr_webclient": usr_webclient ,
            "usr_siv": usr_siv ,
            "tienda": tienda ,
            "empresa": empresa ,
            "funcion": funcion
           },

          success: function (data) {
            alert("Realizado");

          },
          error: function (data) {
           alert("Error");
          }

        });
      });
```

The data array obtain successfully the information, but in the controller i keep receiving this message

```
 A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 23502/7

ERROR: null value in column "idtienda" violates not-null constraint DETAIL: Failing row contains (716, null, null, null, SIN CEDULA, FIZUNCH, uploads/default-user.png, , , SIN TELEFONO, SIN DIRECCION, 01-01-1970, SIN OBSERVACIONES, t, SIN DOMINIO).

INSERT INTO "tbl_ctrl_empleados" ("idtienda", "idtipoempresa", "idfuncion", "cedula", "carnetempleado", "rutafoto", "nombrecompleto", "email", "telefono", "direccion", "fecha_ingreso", "observaciones", "estado", "dominioempleado") VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SIN CEDULA', 'FIZUNCH', 'uploads/default-user.png', '', '', 'SIN TELEFONO', 'SIN DIRECCION', '01-01-1970', 'SIN OBSERVACIONES', TRUE, 'SIN DOMINIO')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/MasterKey/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691
```

But the information goes directly and save it

```
715;45;6;9;"0012208950011K";"010101";"uploads/default-user.png";"LUIS ALFONSO VELAZQUEZ FLOREZA";"LUID@HOTMAIL.COM";"22334411";"NO LO SE";"01-01-1970";"AQUI";TRUE;"AQUI"
```

Please advice me what im doing wrong.

*update*
The schema from my table it's

```
CREATE TABLE key.tbl_ctrl_empleados
(
  idempleado serial NOT NULL,
  idtienda integer NOT NULL,
  idtipoempresa integer NOT NULL,
  idfuncion integer NOT NULL,
  cedula character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  carnetempleado character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  rutafoto character varying(300),
  nombrecompleto character varying(300) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
  telefono character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  direccion character varying(500) NOT NULL,
  fecha_ingreso character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  observaciones character varying(300) NOT NULL,
  estado boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  dominioempleado character varying(300) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_ctrl_empleados_pkey PRIMARY KEY (idempleado),
  CONSTRAINT tbl_ctrl_empleados_idfuncion_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idfuncion)
      REFERENCES key.cat_ctrl_funcion (idfuncion) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_ctrl_empleados_idtienda_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idtienda)
      REFERENCES key.tbl_ctrl_tiendas (idtienda) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT tbl_ctrl_empleados_idtipoempresa_fkey FOREIGN KEY (idtipoempresa)
      REFERENCES key.ft_ctrl_rel_tipoempresa (idrelacion) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE key.tbl_ctrl_empleados
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

The method in my controller:

```
function save_empleado() {
    $valoresReemplazoCedula = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN CEDULA',
    "''" => 'SIN CEDULA'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoCarnet = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN CARNET',
    "''" => 'SIN CARNET'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoEmail = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN EMAIL',
    "''" => 'SIN EMAIL'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoTelefono = array(
    '-' => '',
    ' ' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN TELEFONO',
    "''" => 'SIN TELEFONO'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoDominio = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN DOMINIO',
    "''" => 'SIN DOMINIO'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoNombre = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN NOMBRE',
    "''" => 'SIN NOMBRE'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoObservacion = array(
    'N/A' => 'SIN OBSERVACIONES',
    "''" => 'SIN OBSERVACIONES'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoDireccion = array(
    'N/A' => 'SIN DIRECCION',
    "''" => 'SIN DIRECCION'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoOPEN = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN OPEN',
    "''" => 'SIN OPEN'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoODA = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN ODA',
    "''" => 'SIN ODA'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoWC = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN WEBCLIENT',
    "''" => 'SIN WEBCLIENT'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoSIV = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN SIV',
    "''" => 'SIN SIV'
    );

    $valoresReemplazoQFLOW = array(
    '-' => '',
    'N/A' => 'SIN QFLOW',
    "''" => 'SIN QFLOW'
    );

     $this->load->model('EmpleadoModel');
     // $fechaingresos = $fechaingreso->format('d/m/Y');
     // $fechaingresos = $this->input->post("fecha_ingreso");
     //$fechaingreso= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$this->input->post("date"));
      //$fechaingreso= DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d',$this->input->post("fecha_ingreso"))->format('d/m/Y');
      //echo Datetime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->input->post("fecha_ingreso"))->format('d/m/Y');
     $fechaingreso=$this->input->post("fecha_ingreso");
     $time = strtotime($fechaingreso);
     $fecha = date('d/m/Y',$time);
     $direcciones=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoDireccion, preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',ltrim($this->input->post("direccion"))));
     $nombre=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoNombre, preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',ltrim($this->input->post("nombrecompleto"))));
     $cedula=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoCedula, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("cedula"))));
     $carnet=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoCarnet, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("carnet"))));
     $telefono=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoTelefono, preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',ltrim($this->input->post("telefono"))));
     $observaciones=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoObservacion, preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',ltrim($this->input->post("observaciones"))));
     $email=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoEmail, preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',ltrim($this->input->post("email"))));
     $dominios=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoDominio, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("dominioempleado"))));
     $usr_open=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoOPEN, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("usr_open"))));
     $usr_oda=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoODA, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("usr_oda"))));
     $usr_qflow=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoQFLOW, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("usr_qflow"))));
     $usr_webclient=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoWC, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("usr_webclient"))));
     $siv=$this->reemplazarCadenaAsoc($valoresReemplazoSIV, preg_replace('/\s+/', '',ltrim($this->input->post("usr_siv"))));
     $flag=$this->EmpleadoModel->existe_empleado($carnet,$cedula);
     if ($flag === true) {
       echo '<script>alert("El numero de carnet ya se encuentra registrado.")</script>';
       return;
  }
  $fechaingreso = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->input->post("fecha_ingreso"));

  if (empty($carnet)) {
    $carnet = $this->generarAleatorio(7);
  }
  if( empty($direcciones)){
      $direcciones = 'Sin Direccion';
  }
  if( empty($observaciones)){
      $observaciones = 'Sin Observaciones';
  }
  if( empty($telefono) || $telefono == '0'){
    $telefono = 'Sin Telefono';
  }
  if( empty($dominios) || strcasecmp($dominios, 'No tiene') == 0){
      $dominios = 'Sin Dominio';
  }
  if( empty($cedula)){
    $cedula = 'Sin Cedula';
  }
        $save = array('idtienda'=>$this->input->post("tienda"),'idtipoempresa'=>$this->input->post("empresa"),'idfuncion'=>$this->input->post("funcion"),'cedula'=>strtoupper($cedula),'carnetempleado'=>strtoupper($carnet),
    'rutafoto'=>("uploads/default-user.png"),'nombrecompleto'=>strtoupper($nombre),'email'=>strtoupper($email),'telefono'=>strtoupper($telefono),'direccion'=>strtoupper($direcciones),
    'fecha_ingreso'=>$fecha,'observaciones'=>strtoupper($observaciones),'estado'=>(true),'dominioempleado'=>strtoupper($dominios));
    $idEmpleado = $this->EmpleadoModel->save($save);
    if ($idEmpleado != 0) {
      $this->load->model('USRModel');
      if( empty($usr_open) || strcasecmp($usr_open, 'No tiene')==0){
          $usr_open = 'Sin OPEN';
        }
        if( empty($usr_oda) || strcasecmp($usr_oda, 'No tiene')==0){
            $usr_oda = 'Sin ODA';
          }
          if( empty($usr_webclient) || strcasecmp($usr_webclient, 'No tiene')==0){
              $usr_webclient = 'Sin WEBCLIENT';
            }
            if( empty($usr_qflow) || strcasecmp($usr_qflow, 'No tiene')==0){
                $usr_qflow = 'Sin QFLOW';
              }
              if( empty($siv) || strcasecmp($siv, 'No tiene')==0){
                  $siv = 'Sin SIV';
                }
      $usr = array('idempleado'=>$idEmmpleado,'usr_open'=>strtoupper($usr_open),'usr_oda'=>strtoupper($usr_oda),'usr_webclient'=>strtoupper($usr_webclient),'usr_qflow'=>strtoupper($usr_qflow),'siv'=>strtoupper($siv));
      $idUSR = $this->USRModel->save($usr);
      if ($idUSR != 0) {
        echo '<script>alert("Se han registrado todos los datos")</script>';
        return false;
      }else {
        return true;
      }
    }else {
      return false;
    }
    }
```

and the result that this keeps saving the values but still showing the error

[image]

Comment: you are not passing value for column `idtienda` else goto db and remove constraint not null

Comment: Can you show us the schema for this table

Comment: @Omi the value ` idtienda ` it's passing good. ` idempleado: 715; idtienda: 45; idtipoempresa: 6; idfuncion: 9; cedula: "0012208950011K"; carnetempleado: "010101";rutafoto: "uploads/default-user.png";nombrecompleto: "LUIS ALFONSO VELAZQUEZ FLOREZA";correo: "LUID@HOTMAIL.COM";telefono: "22334411";direccion: "NO LO SE";fechacontrato: "01-01-1970";"AQUI";estado: TRUE;"AQUI" `

Comment: @LuisCardozaBird : update question with code, not in comment, it'll be more helpful for newcomers

Comment: please add php code as well

Comment: check this thats why you getting that error  `INSERT INTO "tbl_ctrl_empleados" ("idtienda", "idtipoempresa", "idfuncion", "cedula", "carnetempleado", "rutafoto", "nombrecompleto", "email", "telefono", "direccion", "fecha_ingreso", "observaciones", "estado", "dominioempleado") VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, 'SIN CEDULA', 'FIZUNCH', 'uploads/default-user.png', '', '', 'SIN TELEFONO', 'SIN DIRECCION', '01-01-1970', 'SIN OBSERVACIONES', TRUE, 'SIN DOMINIO')`

Comment: I hope that help :)

Comment: may be `tienda` is null in your ajax code, make sure value of `tienda` is not null

Comment: @Omi the values are not null, and they save perfectly, but ajax keep saying ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was funny, i change the ajax for a form post, and the values are send perfectly :)

```
<?php echo form_open('empleadoController/save_empleado', $create_form); ?>
```